# How to add one-to-many association in Hibernate to an embedded type?

Tags: java, hibernate, one-to-many

I have an Entity that holds the last instance of a Component:

```
@Entity
public class Customer {
  ...
  @Embedded
  public ServiceCall getLastServiceCall() {...}
  ...
}

@Embeddable
public class ServiceCall() {
  public Date getDate();
  public Status getStatus();
}
```

The `ServiceCall` is embedded in order to call `customer.getLastServiceCall().getDate()` without requiring another table join.

I want to make that association one-to-many, and start saving all `ServiceCall`s, while holding one embedded in the customer.

Hibernate's [Docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-component) (v3.6, which I'm using) states:

> You can also use association annotations in an embeddable object (ie @OneToOne, @ManyToOne, @OneToMany or @ManyToMany). To override the association columns you can use @AssociationOverride.

and it seem that all I should do is add `@OneToMany` to the `LastServiceCall` association.

Will that work for me? If not, what are my alternatives? If yes, how will that affect 2nd level cache, and is there a limitation on updating that embedded instance (I can live with an immutable objects)?

Comment: can you post table structure you are trying to model.

Comment: Customer: ID, Version, creation date, etc. + ServiceCallDate, ServiceCallStatus. I want to have another table, ServiceCall: ID, date, status, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Embeded types are not supposed to have their own identity in the database, so  I don't think you can add @OneToMany to the Customer class on the ServiceCall.

```
  @OneToMany 
  @Embedded
  public ServiceCall getLastServiceCall() {...}
```

However you can add an association to the @Embeded Service call element like so.

```
@Entity 
pubic class HistoricalServiceCall extends ServiceCall 
{
   @Id 
   private String id; 

}


@Embeddable 
public class ServiceCall {

   @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
   @JoinColumn(name="join_column_defined_on_customer_table")
   List<HistoricalServiceCall> getServiceCallHistory(); 
}
```

**Update:** putting FetchType.LAZY on the getServiceCallHistory() is a hint to the JPA provider to wait until you call getServiceCallHistory before it does another select to pull in that association.

So with the setup I am describing if you do customer.getLastServiceCall().getDate() it will not pull 
in the ServiceCallHistory before the relationship is lazy.

Comment: thanks. I've updated my question - I need ServiceCall's fields on the Customer w/o additional joins. Are you suggesting duplicating the ServiceCall fields - one copy in the embedded instance and another in the Historical table?

Comment: I have updated my answer, please don't forget to upvote if you find the answer useful.

Comment: @ams What if we have public List<ServiceCall> getLastServiceCall() ?

Answer (score 1):

What you need is the following:

- A Customer entity
- An embeddable ServiceCall
- A HistoricalServiceCall entity.

The Customer should contain an embedded ServiceCall field (the last service call).

The HistoricalServiceCall entity should have an ID, an embedded ServiceCall field (the data of the HistoricalServiceCall), and, potentially, a ManyToOne association to Customer if you want the OneToMany to be bidirectional.

The Customer should have a OneToMany association to HistoricalServiceCall.

Comment: I don't see the point in adding a OneToMany from ServiceCall to HistoricalServiceCall rather than from Customer to HistoricalServiceCall as I suggest. Moreover, this forbids reusing the ServiceCall embeddable inside HistoricalServiceCall. With ams's answer, you'd have to duplicate all the fields and methods of ServiceCall inside the HistoricalServiceCall class.

Comment: I'm going to combine both your answers. I still need to see the correct relation between `ServiceCall` and its `History` entity

Comment: Even if you put the association inside ServiceCall, the association will still be between the Customer and the HistoricalServiceCall. An embedded object is just used to group some fields together, but it can't be the target of an association.

Comment: Yes - I understand that. I'm going to do a lazy one-to-many, or model the relation just from the `History` side. still TBD.